# Create a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries but not able to push my dictionaries into a list. What mistake am I making.

How data (mongo_data) looks:

```
{
 'url': 'https://goodreads.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'Harry Potter', 'value': '10.0'},
               {'key': 'Discovery of Witches', 'value': '8.5'},],
 'vendor': 'Fantasy' 
 }

 {
 'url': 'https://goodreads.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'Hunger Games', 'value': '10.0'},
               {'key': 'Maze Runner', 'value': '5.5'},],
 'vendor': 'Dystopia' 
 }

 {
 'url': 'https://kindle.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'Twilight', 'value': '5.9'},
               {'key': 'Lord of the Rings', 'value': '9.0'},],
 'vendor': 'Fantasy' 
 }

 {
 'url': 'https://kindle.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'The Handmaids Tale', 'value': '10.0'},
               {'key': 'Divergent', 'value': '9.0'},],
 'vendor': 'Fantasy' 
 }
```

My data that I have gotten from MongoDB:

```
for item in mongo_data:
    url = item['url']
    genre = item['genre']
    books = item['books']
```

My code:

```
url_array = []
url_array.append(url)
unique_urls = set(url_array)
searches = []
main_dict = {}
searches.append(main_dict)
results = []

for url in list(unique_urls):
    book_vals = {}
    main_dict['url'] = url
    main_dict['results'] = [book_vals]
    results.append(book_vals)
    book_vals['genre'] = genre
    book_vals['data'] = books
```

My Result:

```
    {
    "searches": [
        {
            "url": "http://goodreads.com",
            "results": [
                {
                    "genre": "Fantasy",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "Harry Potter",
                            "value": "10.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Discovery of Witches",
                            "value": "8.5"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "url": "http://goodreads.com",
            "results": [
                {
                    "genre": "Dystopia",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hunger Games",
                            "value": "10.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Maze Runner",
                            "value": "5.5"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "url": "http://kindle.com",
            "results": [
                {
                    "genre": "Fantasy",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "Twilight",
                            "value": "5.9"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Lord of the Rings",
                            "value": "9.0"
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "url": "http://kindle.com",
            "results": [
                {
                    "genre": "Dystopia",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "name": "The Handmaids Tale",
                            "value": "10.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Divergent",
                            "value": "9.0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything is being added to the searches array.

But I need them to be grouped by first the **url** in the **main_dict** and then again the **results** to be grouped by **genre**

Expected results:

```
{
    'searches': [
        { 
            'url': 'http://goodreads.com',
            'results': [
               {
                    'genre': 'Fantasy',
                    'data': [
                        {
                            'key': 'Harry Potter',
                            'value': '10.0'
                        }, {
                            'key': 'Discovery of Witches',
                            'value': '8.5'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    'genre': 'Dystopia',
                    'data': [{
                            'key': 'Hunger Games',
                            'value': '10.0'
                        }, {
                            'key': 'Maze Runner',
                            'value': '5.5'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        } ,
        { 
            'url': 'http://kindle.com',
            'results': [
               {
                    'genre': 'Fantasy',
                    'data': [
                        {
                            'key': 'Twilight',
                            'value': '5.9'
                        }, {
                            'key': 'Lord of the Rings',
                            'value': '9.0'
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    'genre': 'Dystopia',
                    'data': [{
                            'key': 'The Handmaids Tale',
                            'value': '10.0'
                        }, {
                            'key': 'Divergent',
                            'value': '9.0'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ] 
        } 
    ]
}
```

Sorry for any data structural issues.

Comment: Why do the first four (as opposed to lets say five) books go with goodreads?

Comment: @KentShikama, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Like how would I as a programmer figure out whether "Harry Potter" is from the URL `http://goodreads.com`? Your `books` data has nothing about URL in it.

Comment: @KentShikama, sorry, i should've made that data clear. I am getting this data from mongoDB. I'll make that edit in my code

Comment: @KentShikama, I have made the edit

Comment: Could you put the all your code..that we can directly change the code and finally what you print.

Comment: @DustyPosa, I have put in all my code. the first block is getting it from mongoDB and then the for loop I have used to group by url. I have also pasted my result

Comment: I'm not interested in your data source as much as how to associate a URL to a book. Maybe it is obvious to you but from the perspective of someone with no context, I have no idea why "Harry Potter" should go with `http://goodreads.com` still. Is it because "Harry Potter" is the first element of the book list and `http://goodreads.com` is also the first element of the URL list? If so how come the fourth element of the book list is also with the first element of the URL list?

Comment: @KentShikama, Makes sense. I will make another edit to show that

Comment: @KentShikama, I have added that as well

Comment: Have you considered using Pandas for this? If the operations you need to perform get any more complex, I think it would absolutely be worth it.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I am not very familiar with pandas. But it does not get any more complex than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. The key is to use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group items with the same URL together.

```
mongo_data = [{
 'url': 'https://goodreads.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'Harry Potter', 'value': '10.0'},
               {'key': 'Discovery of Witches', 'value': '8.5'},],
 'vendor': 'Fantasy' 
 },{
 'url': 'https://goodreads.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'Hunger Games', 'value': '10.0'},
               {'key': 'Maze Runner', 'value': '5.5'},],
 'vendor': 'Dystopia' 
 },{
 'url': 'https://kindle.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'Twilight', 'value': '5.9'},
               {'key': 'Lord of the Rings', 'value': '9.0'},],
 'vendor': 'Fantasy' 
 },{
 'url': 'https://kindle.com/',
 'variables': [{'key': 'The Handmaids Tale', 'value': '10.0'},
               {'key': 'Divergent', 'value': '9.0'},],
 'vendor': 'Fantasy' 
 }]

from itertools import groupby, chain
import json

searches = []
for key, group in groupby(mongo_data, key=lambda chunk: chunk['url']):
    search = {}
    search["url"] = key
    search["results"] = [{"genre": result["vendor"], "data": result["variables"]} for result in group]
    searches.append(search)

print(json.dumps(searches))
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://goodreads.com/",
    "results": [
      {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "Harry Potter",
            "value": "10.0"
          },
          {
            "key": "Discovery of Witches",
            "value": "8.5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "genre": "Dystopia",
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "Hunger Games",
            "value": "10.0"
          },
          {
            "key": "Maze Runner",
            "value": "5.5"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://kindle.com/",
    "results": [
      {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "Twilight",
            "value": "5.9"
          },
          {
            "key": "Lord of the Rings",
            "value": "9.0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "data": [
          {
            "key": "The Handmaids Tale",
            "value": "10.0"
          },
          {
            "key": "Divergent",
            "value": "9.0"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if this is your code, it doesn't make a ton of sense. (I'm assuming that for some reason you didn't share your actual code?)

```
url_array = []
url_array.append(url)
# so- your url_array only has one url?
unique_urls = set(url_array)
searches = []
main_dict = {}
searches.append(main_dict)
# searches will only contain one dict?
results = []

for url in list(unique_urls):
    book_vals = {}
    main_dict['url'] = url
    # as written, you would be over-writing the values in 'main_dict' every time
    main_dict['results'] = [book_vals]
    results.append(book_vals)
    book_vals['genre'] = genre
    book_vals['data'] = books
```

Instead, let me talk about some more general things on this problem. You said

```
But I need them to be grouped by first the url in the main_dict and then again the results to be grouped by genre
```

If we want to take your search results and group them twice, this is how I would do it.

```
class SearchResult:
    url: str
    title: str
    genre: str

result_factory = lambda: {data: []}
search_factory = lambda: {results: default_dict(result_factory)}
searches = default_dict(search_factory)

for search in search_data:
    searches[search.url][search.genre].append(search.title)
```

The basic idea is that when *grouping* stuff, you use a dictionary. so to group searches by urls, you have a dict of urls to a collection of results. Since you want it nested, have a dict of urls to a dict of genres to a list of titles.

The default dict stuff is just syntactic sugar to jumpstart each record instead of checking if it exists and adding the empty object when necessary.